# Self Join? Or am I wrong?

Tags: join, except

We have a table that we use to store customers and items. We need to be able to find customers that have bought one item and have not bought another item:

```
customer     item  
Sally        1   
Sally        2  
Sally        3
John         1  
John         2  
Paul         2
Paul         3
```

We want to find users who bought "1" and not "3". In this case we only want "John".

Comment: but Sally has bought item 3.

Answer (score 10):

No, a self join would not really help, but if your database system has an EXCEPT operator (or something similar, in Oracle it is called MINUS) it would.

Here's how you get your result:

```
SELECT customer FROM Sales
WHERE item = 1
AND customer NOT IN (SELECT customer FROM Sales WHERE item = 3)
```

If you have an EXCEPT operator:

```
SELECT customer FROM Sales WHERE item = 1
EXCEPT
SELECT customer FROM Sales WHERE item = 3
```

Comment: `minus` is Oracle specific. The SQL standard defines `except`

Comment: Correct. At least I am [not alone](http://scottyd99999.blogspot.fr/2009/11/oracles-minus-and-sql-servers-except.html) in assuming it were the other way around. I fixed it.

Comment: I think this is because `MINUS` was introduced in Oracle long before this was defined in the SQL standard.

Comment: *"No, a self join would not really help"* That's not entirely correct. Your first, `NOT IN` solution is actually an anti-semi(self)join. It could well be written with a self LEFT join (and `WHERE .. NOT NULL` check).

Answer (score 4):

Another approach using aggregation:

```
SELECT customer 
FROM sales
GROUP BY customer
HAVING MAX( CASE item WHEN 1 THEN 1
                      WHEN 3 THEN 2
                             ELSE 0 END ) = 1;
```

the Case converts the item-list into 1 for the good item and 2 for the unwanted item, every other item to zero. The maximum will ten be 1 if a good item is in the list for a customer, 2 if a bad item is in the list, 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

In this many-to-many relation between customers and items, you want to find customers with item A and with nonexistent item B. To add a "row does not exist" condition to an SQL query, you can use a `LEFT JOIN`, which represents nonexistent rows as `NULL` values, followed by a `WHERE some_NOT_NULL_column IS NULL`. In a nonexistence join, the `ON` clause has to *completely* specify the criteria for what row needs to not exist, which may mean a longer `ON` clause than some people are used to seeing. Thus the solution using a left join, as suggested by ypercube's comment, becomes as follows:

```
SELECT o1.customer
FROM orders AS o1
LEFT JOIN orders AS o2
ON (o1.customer = o2.customer AND o2.item = 3)
WHERE o1.item = 1
  AND o2.customer IS NULL
```

Comment: This would be my choice, although probably with DISTINCT for any customer who had more than one purchase of item 1.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use a self join, but I would recommend using `EXISTS` (or in this case, `NOT EXISTS`) instead (and it is more efficient than using `IN`):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    foo
WHERE
    item = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM foo AS f WHERE f.customer = foo.customer AND item = 3);
```

Comment: Whether a `[NOT] EXISTS` subquery is more efficient than a `[NOT] IN` subquery depends how the DBMS optimizes such queries.